# Windshield wiper fluid in a temperate climate

Tags: cleaning, windshield-washer

I've moved to the west coast from the east coast and am now living in a place where it'll never snow again. PHEW! I was getting sick of the snowmageddons.

But with the weather so nice, I wonder what I need to use in my windshield wiper reservoir. Is there any reason not to go with straight water? The only thing that bothers me now is bug and tree sap which I find the blue stuff doesn't get off any better than water. Is there a diy additive that can boost plain h20 to make it better for gunk?

Comment: The best way to get tree sap off the screen is not to get it on in the first place. Don't park under trees! In the UK, the "blue stuff" works pretty well, provided you don't let the bugs get baked hard in the sun. UK summer temps are typically 70F to 75F and up to 85 or 90 in a heat-wave, to calibrate what I think "temperate" means.